# rxjs - ngrx - execute multiple operators together(parallel) and dispatch multiple actions in parallel

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

after getting the api result and dispatch the `PlanningPreviewSuccess` action i need to group the result and dispatch another action whose payload accepts the grouped result
how to do that? witch rxjs operator to use?

```
@Effect()
    fetchElencoTicket$ = this.actions$
        .pipe(
            ofType(ActionTypes.PLANNING_PREVIEW_FETCH),
            mergeMap((action: PlanningPreviewFetch) => {
                const {Inizio, Fine, Comune, Attivita} = action.request;
                return this.planningSrv.GetPlanningPreview(Inizio, Fine, Comune, Attivita);
            }),
            map(plannigPreviewResult => { 
                console.log("plannigPreviewResult", plannigPreviewResult);
                return new PlanningPreviewSuccess(plannigPreviewResult);
            }),
            catchError(err => of(console.log("ERROR"),
                new GenericShowSnackBar({ icon: 'error_outline', text: err.error ? err.error.Message : err, duration: 3000 })
            ))
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you want to merge 2 or more observables and individually want their subscribed results, you can use `combineLatest` operator. Here's how you use it:

```
// Usage of combineLatest

let observable1$ = this.yourObservable1;
let observable2$ = this.yourObservable2;

combineLatest(
    observable1$,
    observable2$
).pipe(
    filter(data => !!data), 
    tap(data => console.log(data)) 
    catchError(error => console.log(error))
).subscribe(
  [dataFromObservable1, dataFromObservable2] => {
   // This will subscribe only if all the observables return data
   // Otherwise it will go to catchError
})


// Filter will check if the data is present or not.
// Tap will return the data before subscribing
// catchError ==> Subscription errors are caught in this catchError
```